# Max function as bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis, probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

I have an algebra of bounded functions $A$ that contains the constant functions and is closed under uniform convergence. We also have that if $f \in A$ then $|f| \in A$. I'm trying to show that if $f, g \in A$ then so is $\text{max}(f,g)$. Is there a standard way to write the max function so that I can approximate it as a limit of convergent sequence of bounded functions in $A$.

Comment: $\frac12(f+g + |f-g|)$.

Comment: Oh, that's nice. Thank you.